# JQuery не работает событие клик по SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь повесить событие клик на селектор SVG, но событие не срабатывает. Не могу понять, почему.

```js
$(document).on("click", 'svg', function(e) {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="all_explain">
  <div class="mini_explain"><img src="/images/8.png" alt=""><strong>Рейтинг:</strong>
     <span class="rainting_explain">
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-id='fas' id="fas_1"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-id='fas' id="fas_2"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-id='fas' id="fas_3"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-id='fas' id="fas_4"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-id='fas' id="fas_5"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="thank_you_rating" style="display: none">Спасибо, мы приняли ваш рейтинг!</div>
  </div>
```

Перепробовал разные селекторы, но ничего не помогает.

[Скрин](https://prntscr.com/jmd245)

Может, кто подскажет, куда копать?

Comment: Помочь можем, если вы покажите `html` в вашем вопросе.

Comment: html прикрепил , в браузере формируется так http://prntscr.com/jmda5m

Comment: Интересный вопрос, но где у вас svg в приведенном html?

Comment: вот http://prntscr.com/jmdntk , создаются после загрузки страницы

Comment: А `svg` не  `ajax-ом` случайно грузиться на страницу?

Comment: нет ajax я уже сохраняю результат

Comment: Переделал рейтинг в нормальной верстке и все заработало, похоже ранее использовался плагин для формирование звезд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.rainting_explain', function(e)
    {
     var svg = e.target.parentNode;
     if(svg.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SVG')
      console.log('нажато svg с id = ' + svg.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="rainting_explain"><svg id="fas_1"><rect width="30" height="30" fill="#00c"/></svg></span>
```

Нажмите на синий квадрат.

Comment: как я понимаю стоит некий плагин который создает стили в виде звезд и html браузер рисует следующий http://prntscr.com/jmdmuz  , то есть стили уже вырисовуются после загрузки страницы , как я понимаю

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, Значит надо добавлять событие по onload. Поправил код.

Comment: все равно не видит события , может событие нужно вешать на детей http://prntscr.com/jmdu6y

Comment: если вешаю событие на класс rainting_explain то все ок а если ниже то не работает http://prntscr.com/jmdujz  , может можно на детей както повесить класса rainting_explain ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, переписал всё по нажатию на class rainting_explain. Теперь должно работать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, почему не написали мне ответ?

Comment: не работает , там какая-то другая проблема что не работает событие клик при клике именно на звезду если мимо звезды то все ок , но вариант мимо мне не подходит , почему клик не работает именно на звездах мне не понятно

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, так я же вам уже дал ответ (смотрите изменённый код). И так однозначно должно работать.

Comment: да я пробовал ваш код но он не работал , событие клик вообще не работало на этом элементе

Comment: то есть там проблема не в вашем кода а вообще в событии клик

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, добавьте пожалуйста в ваш вопрос код где `<span class="rainting_explain">` наполняется svg.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник Если вопрос не решен, просьба предоставить  web  архив проекта или его часть - где проблемы (рейтинг) . Гадание на кофейной гуще может быть вечным.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вещаете событие на весь документ а не на свг.
Попробуйте так:

```
$( "svg" ).click(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: нет события кликаю http://prntscr.com/jmd7vb , я делал тестовый метод чтобы получать селекторы куда я кликаю то во всех местах отображается а именно на моих звездах пусто $('body').click(function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
});